# Potential leak of an object stored into "test"

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I am working on an app in Xcode and I need some help.

```
- (IBAction)test:(id)sender {
    game *test = [[game alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];

    [self presentViewController:test animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I am getting the following error and I don't know how to fix it.

> Potential leak of an object stored into "test"

Comment: *sidenote:* use Capital letter for class name. what is the parent class of `game` ? `UIViewController` ? Did you use ARC ?

Comment: is your `game` is subclass of viewcontroller?

Comment: It is another view in the same project

Comment: @LoverofApple: is that class is subclass of `UIViewController`?

Comment: Consider enabling ARC.

Comment: What is ARC. Sorry I am new to the language

Comment: @LoverofApple It is very important to know about ARC, check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226

Comment: Because you have allocated a object as test.But no where you release the object so there is a leak.Please release the object.And one more thing according to coding guideline Please make sure Your first letter of class name should be Capital.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not using ARC, you should `autorelease` your object:

```
game *test = [[[game alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil] autorelease];
```

When you present the controller, it will be retained for you, but when you dismiss it, it will automatically be released for you. Your current code will probably result in a leak (unless you manually `release` elsewhere). Using `autorelease` (or explicitly `release` after `presentViewController`) will prevent both the warning as well as the leak.

Comment: But now I get the crash message EXC_Bad_Access. How do I fix this?

Comment: @LoverofApple This is a sign of memory management issues. The problem is not with the code in your question, but undoubtedly something else. I'd suggest you check out [My App Crashed, Now What?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1). You might also want to temporarily turn on [exception breakpoints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) as well as zombies as discussed in ...

Comment: ... the latter part of Apple's [Locating memory issues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH11-SW1). Also, perform "Analyze" on your "Product" menu in Xcode and make sure you have a clean bill of health there before doing anything else.

Comment: kk I did analyze it and there were no issues

Comment: @LoverofApple Then zombies, exception breakpoints, and other tips in the "My App Crashed" link will help you track it down. But the problem is not with the code in your question, so it's hard for us to offer any concrete counsel. You have to identify precisely what is causing the crash, and if the solution isn't immediately obvious, post a new question. But no one can help you until you use one of the above techniques to identify where the crash is taking place and then share the relevant code with us.

Comment: Oh ARC as in Automatic Reference Counting

Comment: @LoverofApple Yes. If using automatic reference counting (ARC), the `autorelease` is not needed. But if using manual reference counting (sometimes referred here as MRC), then explicit `autorelease` or `release` is needed.

Comment: @LoverofApple I know. I'd encourage you to use ARC in the future, but you don't have to and my original answer was predicated on the fact that you weren't using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not used the ARC, so you can need to `autorelease` the objcet.

when you are making the objcet then it's `reatin count` get be increment by 1. but after your work is done your retain count not being decreases that's why this error (leak) happen. so if you you used the autorelease then `autorelease pool` manage your retain count after dismiss the viewcontroller decreases the `retain count`.